# Update ANN's training set

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

Assume an ANN has trained by 1GB size training data using a long time.
Do we need  train the data again when just a few rows in the training data changed?
or is the design of  ANN  error?

Answer (score 2):

In general, the answer would be yes. Here's why...

First of all, 1GB of training data is a relative measure, since it gives no indication of the *number of training samples*. Perhaps each training sample is 1MB in size (maybe an image), leaving you with only about 1,000 samples which *may* not be enough.

Secondly, it is important to know the architecture of the neural network in order to address the question of retraining fully. If the components in your training set that was updated correspond to nodes that may be heavily influenced in terms of the usage, then a retrain is most certainly in order. Of course, the converse is not necessarily true, as it may not be immediately apparent how the interconnectedness of neural network may be influenced by a change in the input.

Thirdly, a neural network is meant to represent a type of complex pattern-matcher, trained to recognize some input relationship, and produce a possible output relationship. From this naive point of view, a change in input should surely correspond to a change in output. As such, a change in the training data may very well correspond to a change in the expected output data. And, even if it doesn't, the input pattern has changed, which may imply that the output pattern also changed.

Let's consider the following example. Assume your neural network is trained to match paintings with artists and it's been success in making [the following match to Leonardo da Vinci](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mona_Lisa.jpg):

[image]

Now it may be trained well enough to also assert that the following images are "painted" by the same artist:

[image]

[image]

This may be because you trained your neural network on your favourite past-time of balloon an Lego figurines. However, now a number of your input samples change, specifically those associated with the Mona Lisa. Instead they resemble your new favourite past-time... freehand mouse-drawing:

[image]

Despite what you say, in general the artistry of the above image doesn't really match that of the earlier ones. As such, your pattern-matcher may not appropriately recognize this as a piece of art made by Leonardo da Vinci. So it's fair to say that retraining it on images of this sort should be in order.

---

You probably have a number of options:

1. Test how effective it is to retrain your neural network given the change in training data. That would allow you to answer the question yourself, and give some insight into the architecture of your neural network.
2. Retrain your neural network on just the changes, which could be considered *new* training data. The value of this might depend heavily on your architecture, the complexity of the samples as well as the training quantity (not size).
3. Perform a complete retrain and test the efficacy.